# Operation on value of a particular key in a dictionary stored as a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

Need to perform an operation in a dictionary which has a values as a list of dictionaries

```
my_dicts = \
       {"A": [
             { 'key1 a' : 'value1',
               'key2 a' : 'value2' 
             },

             { 'key1 a' : 'value3',  
               'key2 a' : 'value4' 
             }
            ],

        "B": [
             { 'key1 b' : 'value5',
               'key2 b' : 'value6' 
             },

             { 'key1 b' : 'value7',  
               'key2 b' : 'value8' 
             }
            ]
}
```

How can we peform an operaion on all the values who have "key2" as substring in its key?
i.e. operation on value2, value4, value6 and value8. "key2" is a substring of "key2 a", "key2 b"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll *have* to loop over *all* keys of *all* nested dictionaries:

```
# generator expression over all values for keys that contain `key2`.
key2values = (v for lst in my_dicts.itervalues() 
                    for dct in lst
                        for k, v in dct.iteritems()
                            if 'key2' in k)

for value in key2values:
    # loops over `value2`, `value4`, `value6`, `value8` in an arbitrary order.
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> key2values = (v for lst in my_dicts.itervalues() 
...                     for dct in lst
...                         for k, v in dct.iteritems()
...                             if 'key2' in k)
>>> for value in key2values:
...     print value
... 
value2
value4
value6
value8
```

If you want to avoid looping over everything, you'll need to rethink your data structure, or build and maintain an index into the structure.

If you needed to manipulate the key-value pair, you need to have more information. You can include the 'parent' dictionary in the loop:

```
key2values = (dct, k, v for lst in my_dicts.itervalues() 
                    for dct in lst
                        for k, v in dct.iteritems()
                            if 'key2' in k)
```

and unpack that information when looping over the generator:

```
for parent, key, value in key2values:
    # parent[key] is equal to value.
```

Comment: Another thing if i need to check a substring for v too can i write "if 'x' in v" after the last line for key2values and what if the case is matched and i want to update the old value and update it in my_dicts

Comment: @user1007839: Updated to show how you could change values in the parent dictionary. You can adjust the `if` part of the generator expression to match values too, yes.